# How to make Octopus Deploy trigger a new release when a new release made on GitHub?

Tags: automation, octopus-deploy

I have a GitHub project that I'm using to trigger new releases on Octopus. I can see triggers for machine changes, or timed things, but not specifically when a new release is created on GitHub. This seems odd, certainly Azure offers it.

Does GitHub need to be configured to provide a feed, or is it possible for Octopus to check for new releases on GitHub and then use that to trigger a new release?

Answer (score 1):

Octopus can be configured as either the target of a [push from GitHub](https://octopus.com/blog/publishing-a-package-to-octopus-with-github-actions) or you can set up a feed in Github, and [pull](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/package-repositories/github-feeds) from that feed.

In your case, it sounds like you want a push mechanism, such as [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) to do the heavy lifting.